# How to find the number of tabs opened in ie using autoit?

Tags: autoit

I need to open a specific tab in Internet Explorer. As of now I am trying to loop through each tab using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and check the title, but I need number of tabs to end the loop. Can anyone suggest me how to get the number of tabs? Also a better alternative to get a specific tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this

```
#include <IE.au3>
Local $aIE[2]
Local $i = 1, $oIE
While 1
    $oIE = _IEAttach("", "instance", $i)
    If @error = $_IEStatus_NoMatch Then ExitLoop
    ConsoleWrite(_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "title") & @CRLF)
;~  ConsoleWrite(_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl") & @CRLF)
    ReDim $aIE[$i + 1]
    $aIE[$i] = $oIE
    $aIE[0] = $i
    $i += 1
WEnd
```